# Where am I supposed to place types/interfaces for them to become available globally?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

One question that nags me all the time about TypeScript is - where am I supposed to place types/interfaces that accompany the given class? They are many and they are used all around the code base, so that I'd prefer to not have to import them all the time, but rather simply by available globally like ordinary primitives are (e.g. string, number, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although using global types is highly discouraged and not recommended you can achieve it in a pretty simple way - create `.ts` file that doesn't have `import/export` statements (basically isn't defined as module). Everything within that folder will be globally accessible in other typescript files.

Only thing you'll need is to include those `.ts` files in compilation - one of the ways is through `include` property of `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*" // or whatever path suits you fine
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have a link to a resource where's this approach is described in more detail?

Comment: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

You can declare modules in the global scope by creating a type file e.g. `globals.d.ts` that looks like this:

```
declare global {

}
```

Types you declare inside will be available globally. Then you just need to make sure that file is included by typescript. Typescript will include all `.ts`, `.d.ts`, and `.tsx` by default.

Comment: Is there more sustainable way, like throwing everything in one big file, doesn't sound maintainable or graceful.